# Django: child models with the same properties, but different attributes on those properties

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models in my database that, if I don't do anything "creative" will look something like this:

```py
class AbstractModel(models.Model):

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ModelA(AbstractModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class ModelB(AbstractModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
```

The only real difference between `ModelA` and `ModelB` is that I want `ModelA`'s `name` property to be non-nullable, but writing it like this, especially when you consider that I've got about 10 different fields to write in much the same situation, feels very not-DRY.  Surely, there's a better/smarter way?

Note that this isn't about validation, so moving the blank-checking up into a form isn't going to solve the problem.  I want the database column to be `NOT NULL` for `ModelA` and `NULL` for `ModelB`.

Comment: The null-able version of a field seems like the general, more abstract case. Could you put the fields which are null-able into the abstract class and explicitly state the non-nullable ones at the concrete case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelA` and `ModelB` probably represent entities which don't have as much in common as it appears when you list their properties. The fact that one needs values just to live and the other doesn't suggests their behavior and responsibilities require independant representation. They do different things for you.